# Calling ASP webpage from C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am trying to call a localhost webpage I created with ASP from a console application written with C#.
I tried the following code:

`Process.Start("http://localhost:49268/B:/Projects/Transformation/Transformation/View/Pages/HomePage.aspx");`

but the browser says:

> Firefox can not connect to the server on localhost: 49268 build.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable, please try again later. 
>   If you can not access any other site, please check the network /
>   Internet connection.  If your computer or network is protected by a
>   firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the
>   Internet.

I can't understand what the problem is!
How can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What about the obvious - there is no site listening at port 49268 on your machine?

Comment: Did, you try by pinging this url manually in web browser?

Comment: Is this application supposed to be an website server? If that is the case, take a look at [Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana)

Comment: How do I know the ports the have listeners??

Comment: FYI `B:` should be escaped

Comment: What happens when you browse same URL in browser. You need to host that project in IIS.

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar if you haven't started a site on this port, it doesn't have anything listening. Also, the URL is wrong - after `:` should come only a port number while you have a local file path

Comment: FYI ``B: not at all required. Wrong URL``

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar what are you trying to do? Display a local HTML file? Or do you have a site running *somewhere* and you want your browser to display a page on it?

Comment: I have developped an asp project witrh many pages, and I want to call the homepage from a c# application

Comment: if I esaped the B:, how do I give the page URL ?

Comment: Do you have any other web sites running under IIS at the moment?